# Classic Button in Classic editor

Tags: posts

After I upgraded to Wordpress 5.5 the preview button in the classic editor does not work.  When I click on it, it simply returns me to the visual page.

Also, when trying to edit a post that is more than a screen, the whole post shows.  To find the menu items associated with a post page, I have to scroll up to the top of the post page.

I've searched this forum and found nothing helpful.

Comment: Can you please check your console log and paste it here.

Comment: 5.5 updated jQuery and removed jQuery migrate, I suspect your theme or plugins aren't compatible with the new version. There's plugins on .org that can re-add jQuery migrate, updating the plugins you have might also resolve the issue. Otherwise, none of the classic editor features that rely on JS will be operational because JS elsewhere  triggered an error and prevented it from setting itself up.